# Set notation what does the bar symbol mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In set notation could somebody explain the meaning of $\mid$ in the equation below please? How does it read?

I read it as $s$ and $j$ are an element of $E$ but what does the $j \mid$ mean?

[image: summation]

Similarly in this equation what does the comma mean?

[image: flow]

Comment: Short answer: such that. Respectively, $j$ such that the ordered pair $(j,i)$ is in $E$, $j$ such that the ordered pair $(s,j)$ is in $E$.

Comment: See [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate).

Comment: @StevenWagter: You should post your comment as an answer. (And explain why commas are used, and often omitted, in  lists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the $m_{j,i}$'s are elements of the set $M$, and that each pair $(j,i) \subset I \subset \Bbb{N}^2$  is an index of an element in $M$, where $I$ is an indexing set. Then

$$Inputs(i) = \sum_{j|(j,i) \in E} m_{j,i}$$ means *"Given some fixed input value $i$, sum those elements in $M$ whose index $(j,i)$ satisfies $(j,i) \in E$*.

Here $E$ is some subset of $\Bbb{N}^2$. So we loop over all the $j$'s ($i$ is fixed) and add the terms corresponding to those $j$'s which satisfy $(j,i) \in E$.

In the second picture, the comma can be read as a vertical bar. They have the same meaning in this case.

**EDIT** - [in response to Shaun](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052908/set-notation-what-does-the-bar-symbol-mean/3052941?noredirect=1#comment6297447_3052941):

$I$ is some set used for indexing the elements in $M$, which must exist since otherwise the subscript of ordered pairs doesn't make sense. For example, take a $2\times2$-matrix. Then if you want to take the matrix element of the first row, second column, one writes $a_{1,2}$. But what is really going on, is that you have the index set $I = \{ (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$, where there is a one-to-one correspondence between elements in $I$ and the set of matrix elements.

For example, returning to our situation, taking the same indexing set $I$ as above and letting $E = \{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$, then $Inputs(2) = m_{2,2}$.

Another example of indexing sets: $$1/2+1/4+1/8 +... = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{N} } \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Here $\Bbb{N}$ is the indexing set.

Comment: Where did the $I$ come from? Don't you mean $E$?

Comment: @Shaun added some clarification, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you, @StevenWagter :)